# how to fetch logs content between two dates in windows powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, logging, powershell-5.0

In our project, we are getting AppDynamics logs(application logs) and machine logs and sometime the the size of the logs increase which eats out the disk size. What I am trying to do it is to get the content between two dates like 10 Nov and 13 Nov and delete the rest. Since we are working in windows environment, this needs to be done in powershell. It is easier to handle such things in linux but I am not good at powershell scripting. Below is the code snippet.

```
[AD Thread-Metric Reporter1] 10 Nov 2019 14:47:32,899 ERROR ManagedMonitorDelegate - Error sending metrics - will requeue for later transmission
com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.metrics.MetricSendException: Connection back off limitation in effect: /controller/instance/702/metrics
    at com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.AMetricSubscriber.publish(AMetricSubscriber.java:350)
    at com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.MetricReporter.run(MetricReporter.java:113)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.AgentScheduledExecutorServiceImpl$SafeRunnable.run` ]
[AD Thread-Metric Reporter1] 11 Nov 2019 14:46:32,899 ERROR ManagedMonitorDelegate - Error sending metrics - will requeue for later transmission
com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.metrics.MetricSendException: Connection back off limitation in effect: /controller/instance/702/metrics
    at com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.AMetricSubscriber.publish(AMetricSubscriber.java:350)
    at com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.MetricReporter.run(MetricReporter.java:113)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.AgentScheduledExecutorServiceImpl$SafeRunnable.run` ]
[extension-scheduler-pool-5] 13 Nov 2019 18:45:40,634  INFO ReportMetricsConfigSupplier - Basic metrics will be collected and reported through the SIM extension because SIM is enabled.
[extension-scheduler-pool-8] 14 Nov 2019 18:47:18,650  INFO ReportMetricsConfigSupplier - Basic metrics will be collected and reported through the SIM extension because SIM is enabled.` ]
```

Code Snippet with file paths

```
# Get Start Time
$startDTM = (Get-Date)
$zstart = Read-Host -prompt '
Enter your start date in "10 Nov" format. Start date must be earlier than stop date.'
$zstop = Read-Host -prompt 'Enter your stop date in "13 Nov" format.  Stop date must be later than start date.'
# $zstart = '10 Nov'
# $zstop = '13 Nov'
$zstart= Select-String $zstart "$env:userprofile\Desktop\machine-log.txt" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LineNumber
$zstop= Select-String $zstop "$env:userprofile\Desktop\machine-logtxt" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LineNumber
$AppLog = gc $env:userprofile\Desktop\machine-log.txt 
$i = 0
$array = @()
foreach ($line in $AppLog){
foreach-object { $i++ }
if (($i -ge $zstart) -and ($i -le $zstop))
{$array += $line}}
$array | Out-File -encoding ascii -filepath $env:userprofile\Desktop\logfile-output.txt
```

The ERROR i get while executing the script.

```
   8923 8924 8925 8926 8927 8928 8929 8930 8931 8932 8933 8934 8935 8936 8937 8938 8939 8940 8941 8942 8943 
8944 8945 8946 8947 8948". Error: "Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to 
type "System.Int32"."
At C:\Users\xa_abbasmn\Documents\Logs\test.ps1:13 char:5
+ if (($i -ge $zstart) -and ($i -le $zstop))
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComparisonFailure

Could not compare "18" to "1 15 16 17 31 45 46 47 48 62 76 77 91 105 106 107 121 135 136 137 151 152 196 210 
211 225 239 240 241 255 269 270 271 285 299 300 314 315 329 330 331 332 346 390 404 447 448 449 463 477 478 
492 506 507 508 522 536 537 538 552 566 567 581 582 583 627 641 642 643 657 671 685 686 687
```

The powershell and windows version:
Name: Windows PowerShell ISE Host - Version : 5.1.14409.1018
Name: Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 64bit

your help will be highly obliged.
Best regards,

Comment: comment to me when you have added the following to your question: What version windows? 32 or 64-bit? What version powershell? What two dates?

Comment: The important point is to recognize, that log entries below the line belong to the same entry and then recognize with new date.

Comment: comment to me when you have added the following to your question: what is the full path / name to the logfile?

Comment: @somebadhat the full path to the file is C:\logs\machine-logs.log

Comment: comment me after you have made the following changes to your question: add the path to your logfile to the question.  Take the code snippet (09 Nov? to 14 Nov) from the logfile you used in your failed attempt to use my answer and replace the code snippet in your question.

Comment: Error: "Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" 
to type "System.Int32"."
At C:\Users\xa_abbasmn\Documents\Logs\test.ps1:15 char:5
+ if (($i -ge $zstart) -and ($i -le $zstop))
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComparisonFailure

Comment: thats is the error that o get while executing the script and input string

Comment: don't use quotes around 10 Nov

Comment: Just ran the script again.  Still works for me.

Comment: `"$env:userprofile\Desktop\machine-logtxt"` you forgot the period

Comment: I did exactly as you instructed and which period i forgot? I am getting the same above error.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 64-bit. Powershell 5. Does not require admin privileges.

How to quickly and efficiently extract text from a large logfile from input1 to input2 using powershell 5?

Sample logfile below.

For testing purposes copy your logfile to the desktop and name it logfile.txt

What is the default text editor in Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 64-bit?  See line 42.
What program do you have associated with .txt files?  See line 42.

```
# Get Start Time
$startDTM = (Get-Date)
$zstart = Read-Host -prompt '
Enter your start date in "10 Nov" format (w/o quotes). Start date must be earlier than stop date.'
$zstop = Read-Host -prompt 'Enter your stop date in "13 Nov" format (w/o quotes).  Stop date must be later than start date.'
# $zstart = '10 Nov'
# $zstop = '13 Nov'
$zstart= Select-String $zstart "$env:userprofile\Desktop\logfile.txt" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LineNumber
$zstop= Select-String $zstop "$env:userprofile\Desktop\logfile.txt" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LineNumber
$AppLog = gc $env:userprofile\Desktop\logfile.txt 
$i = 0
$array = @()
foreach ($line in $AppLog){
foreach-object { $i++ }
if (($i -ge $zstart) -and ($i -le $zstop))
{$array += $line}}
$array | Out-File -encoding ascii -filepath $env:userprofile\Desktop\logfile-edited.txt 
# begin get file size 
$y = (Get-ChildItem "$env:userprofile\Desktop\logfile.txt" | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
$y = [System.Math]::Round(($y.Sum /1KB),2) 
$z = (Get-ChildItem "$env:userprofile\Desktop\logfile-edited.txt" | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
$z = [System.Math]::Round(($z.Sum /1KB),2) 
#   end get file size 
# get Stop Time
$endDTM = (Get-Date) 
Write-Host "
Extracted $z KB from $y KB. The extraction took $(($endDTM-$startDTM).totalseconds) seconds"
start-process -wait notepad $env:userprofile\Desktop\logfile-edited.txt
remove-item $env:userprofile\Desktop\logfile-edited.txt 
exit
```

logfile.txt:

```
[AD Thread-Metric Reporter1] 09 Nov 2019 14:48:32,899 ERROR ManagedMonitorDelegate - Error sending metrics
com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.metrics.MetricSendException: Connection back off limitation
at com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.AMetricSubscriber.publish(AMetricSubscriber.java:350)
at com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.MetricReporter.run(MetricReporter.java:113)
at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.AgentScheduledExecutorServiceImpl$SafeRunnable.run ]

[AD Thread-Metric Reporter1] 10 Nov 2019 14:47:32,899 ERROR ManagedMonitorDelegate - Error sending metrics
com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.metrics.MetricSendException: Connection back off limitation
at com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.AMetricSubscriber.publish(AMetricSubscriber.java:350)
at com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.MetricReporter.run(MetricReporter.java:113)
at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.AgentScheduledExecutorServiceImpl$SafeRunnable.run ]

[AD Thread-Metric Reporter1] 11 Nov 2019 14:46:32,899 ERROR ManagedMonitorDelegate - Error sending metrics
com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.metrics.MetricSendException: Connection back off limitation
at com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.AMetricSubscriber.publish(AMetricSubscriber.java:350)
at com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.MetricReporter.run(MetricReporter.java:113)
at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.AgentScheduledExecutorServiceImpl$SafeRunnable.run ]

[extension-scheduler-pool-5] 13 Nov 2019 18:45:40,634  INFO ReportMetricsConfigSupplier - Basic metrics will be collected 
[extension-scheduler-pool-8] 14 Nov 2019 18:47:18,650  INFO ReportMetricsConfigSupplier - Basic metrics will be collected
```

Results of running script on logfile.txt:

```
[AD Thread-Metric Reporter1] 10 Nov 2019 14:47:32,899 ERROR ManagedMonitorDelegate - Error sending metrics
com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.metrics.MetricSendException: Connection back off limitation
at com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.AMetricSubscriber.publish(AMetricSubscriber.java:350)
at com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.MetricReporter.run(MetricReporter.java:113)
at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.AgentScheduledExecutorServiceImpl$SafeRunnable.run ]

[AD Thread-Metric Reporter1] 11 Nov 2019 14:46:32,899 ERROR ManagedMonitorDelegate - Error sending metrics
com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.metrics.MetricSendException: Connection back off limitation
at com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.AMetricSubscriber.publish(AMetricSubscriber.java:350)
at com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.MetricReporter.run(MetricReporter.java:113)
at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.AgentScheduledExecutorServiceImpl$SafeRunnable.run ]

[extension-scheduler-pool-5] 13 Nov 2019 18:45:40,634  INFO ReportMetricsConfigSupplier - Basic metrics will be collected
```

[Powershell in four hours at Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=plqpmZruOYk)

[Parse and extract text with powershell at Bing](https://www.bing.com/search?q=Parse%20and%20extract%20text%20with%20powershell)

How to quickly and efficiently extract text from a large logfile from line x to line y using powershell 5?

How to quickly and efficiently extract text from a large logfile from date1 to date2 using powershell 5?

Comment: Thank you so much @somebadhat for brief explanantion. When i setup the code as you instructed then I get the following issue "Enter your start date in "10 Nov" format. Start date must be earlier than stop date.: "10 Nov"
Enter your stop date in "13 Nov" format.  Stop date must be later than start date.: "13 Nov" ->
Extracted 0 KB from 2608.54 KB. The extraction took 16.8283796 seconds"